# pg_dump redirect error messages

Tags: postgresql, cron, backup, logging, pg-dump

I'm writing a cron job to backup a database using pg_dump. I'm looking for a way of redirecting error messages so I can email a backup log file at the end of the process. Is this possible? I can't see anything in the pg_dump documentation that would support this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't find any redirection information in the documentation of _any Unnix based tool because not the tool will redirect the output but the shell which executes that tool will do this. So the usual things work for `pg_dump` to:

```
pg_dump .... 2>/tmp/pg_dump.log
```

For more possibilities you may lookup the section REDIRECTION of the shell using the command

```
man bash
```

Comment: OK, that makes sense. I need to learn a bit more about bash scripting. Thanks.

Comment: looks like a useful start - http://www.mail-archive.com/pgsql-general@postgresql.org/msg72894.html